# Just messed up a server misusing chown, how to execute it correctly?

Tags: ssh, ftp, chown, file-ownership, dedicated-hosting

I'm moving from an old shared host to a dedicated server at MediaTemple. The server is running Plesk CP, but, as far as I can tell, there's no way via the Interface to do what I want to do.

On the old shared host, running cPanel, I creative a .zip archive of all the website's files. I downloaded this to my computer, then uploaded it with FTP to the new host account I'd set up.

Finally, I logged in via SSH, navigated to the directory the zip was stored in (something like `var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/` and ran the `unzip` command on the file `sitearchive.zip`. This extracted everything just the fine. The site appeared to work just fine.

**The problem**: When I tried to edit a file through FTP, I got `Error - 160: Permission Denied.` When I Get Info for the file I'm trying to edit, it says the owner and group is `swimwir1`.

I attemped to use `chown` at this point to change owner - and yes, as you may be able to tell, I'm a little inexperienced in SSH ;) luckily the server was new, since the command I ran - `chown -R newuser /` appeared to mess a load of stuff up. The reason I used `/` on the end rather than `/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs/` was because I'd already `cd`ed into their, so I presumed the `/` was relative to where I was working. This may be the case, I have no idea, either way - Plesk was no longer accessible, although Apache and things continued to work. I realised my mistake, and deciding it wasn't worth the hassle of 1) being an amateur and 2) trying to fix it, I just reprovisioned the server to start afresh.

**So - what do I do to change the owner of these files *correctly*?**

Thanks for helping out a confused beginner!

Jack

Comment: Realised my mistake, does this belong on ServerFault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command does indeed specify an absolute path to the root of the filesystem.  Any path that begins with a '/' is absolute.  You need:

```
chown -R newuser .
```

or:

```
chown -R newuser /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/httpdocs
```